# Add the difference in hours and minutes in c #

Tags: c#, date, datetime-format

Hi I have to run uses sum of time differences in the following format:

1. StartEnd[0]: 08:50
2. StartEnd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz722.png): 10:30
3. StartEnd[2]: 12:30
4. StartEnd[3]: 15:30

   **result**=(StartEnd [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz722.png) -StartEnd[0])+(StartEnd[3]-StartEnd[2])

How can I get the result value in the HH: mm format?

**C# Code:**

```
String[] HourAndMinute = new String[100];
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    HourAndMinute[conta] = dr["StartEnd"].ToString();
    conta++;
}
conta++;
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < conta / 2; i++)
{

    TimeSpan tempoUscita = TimeSpan.Parse(HourAndMinute[i]);
    TimeSpan tempoIngresso = TimeSpan.Parse(HourAndMinute[i + 1]);
    totalSum = totalSum + (tempoUscita - tempoIngresso);
    n++;
}

Totale = "" + totalSum.Hours.ToString().Replace("-", "").ToString() + ":" + totalSum.Minutes.ToString().Replace("-","").ToString();
```

**Sql Query:**

```
select FORMAT(DataCreazione,'HH:mm') as StartEnd
from Marcatura
where  (Stato='Enter' or Stato='Exit')
```

**Table Sql Image:**

[image]

Comment: You want the sum of all rows?

Comment: `TimeSpan.Parse`?

Comment: `dr["StartEnd"]` <= what is the data type for that column? Is it `TimeSpan` or `DateTime`? If so use that type directly to do your computations, do not convert it to string first.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes

Comment: @Igor 
is a string formatted in HH: mm format taken from the sql server

Comment: @Amy 
The idea is that but how is the implementation?

Comment: Does SQL Server have the data as `Time` or `DateTime` or is it stored there as a `varchar`? Is it being returned like this because of the query or because of an incorrect schema (storing dates/times as strings)? If it is the query then change the query to return data you can work with and most likely you could do the calculation in the query itself.

Comment: You almost certainly end up having to re-think that table.  Big bummer when it starts at 11pm and ends at 1am.  Make Start and End separate columns in the table.

Comment: @HansPassant 
it's limited to the current day so there's not that kind of problem, you've got an idea of ​​how I could do it

Comment: It is still by far the best solution, you don't depend on query result order that way either.  The next thing that is going to go wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant 
What do you mean by The next thing is going wrong?

Comment: @riki - The values in the table are order dependent which is bad design. Each row should have self contained data. If you had a start/end column per row then the order no longer matters, you could retrieve and calculate timespans independent of the previous or next row as well as filter rows. Example: In your existing schema write a query to retrieve a count of all records that started after 14:00 but ended before 17:00? If you had 2 columns this would be trivial...

Comment: Also `select FORMAT(DataCreazione,'HH:mm') as StartEnd` <= **do not do that**. Return the value as a `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` (depending on if it is a DateTime or Time in SQL). Types exist for a reason! Use them. You can't do math on a string, you cant execute calculations on a string. Return and use the native type. Conversion to string should happen at the last possible moment in the presentation layer of the application (when the user views the data).

Comment: @Igor 
Unfortunately I always do a bit of mess when it comes to date .. anyway the format of the column is datetime

Comment: @igor 
I wrote this possible solution but the minutes are not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the time entries recorded as *DateTime*, read these *as is* (no string, no format) and convert them to *TimeSpan*:

```
DateTime[] startEnd = new DateTime[4];

// Read data from table. 
// For demonstration, array is here filled manually with your values:
startEnd[0] = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(50);
startEnd[1] = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(30);
startEnd[2] = DateTime.Today.AddHours(12).AddMinutes(30);
startEnd[3] = DateTime.Today.AddHours(15).AddMinutes(30);

TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan(0);

// Add/subtract the timespans in pairs.
for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i += 2)
{
    totalTime += startEnd[i + 1].Subtract(startEnd[i]);
}

// Display totalTime as formatted text.
Console.WriteLine(totalTime.ToString("hh':'mm"));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
TimeSpan totalSum = TimeSpan.Zero;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string[] HourAndMinute = dr["StartEnd"].ToString().Split(); //This String contains 08:50 10:30 ...
    TimeSpan tsStart = TimeSpan.Parse(HourAndMinute[0].Trim());
    TimeSpan tsEnd = TimeSpan.Parse(HourAndMinute[1].Trim());
    totalSum += tsEnd - tsStart;
}
```

---

Well, now you have changed the question completely, first `StartEnd` was `08:50 10:30` now every record contains `08:50` or `10:30`. That datamodel doesn't look good, however...

```
TimeSpan totalSum = TimeSpan.Zero;
List<TimeSpan> orderedTimespans = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => TimeSpan.Parse(r.Field<string>("StartEnd")))
    .OrderBy(ts => ts)
    .ToList();

for (int index = 0; index < orderedTimespans.Count; index+=2)
{
    TimeSpan tsStart = orderedTimespans[index];
    TimeSpan tsEnd = orderedTimespans[index + 1];
    totalSum += tsEnd - tsStart;
}
```

Comment: What if an entry starts before midnight and ends sometime after?

Comment: @blins: Why you ask me? Is that a valid use case? If you want to support that you should use `DateTime` instead of `TimeSpan`.

Comment: It may not be a concern for the OP but just mentioning it since your answer doesn't warn about the case.

Comment: @blins: well, as a workaround(if he can't change the type to `DateTime`), he could use this: `if (tsStart > tsEnd)
     tsEnd = tsEnd.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));`. But this fails if `tsEnd - tsStart` is over 24h. I try to avoid mention or fix things that are no problem because that distracts from the real question and answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter 
at the cycle I have this error: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'.

Comment: @riki? Where? In which line exactly? Maybe you have a value `StartEnd` without spaces.

Comment: @TimSchmelter 
exactly on the TimeSpan tsEnd = TimeSpan.Parse (HourAndMinute [1] .Trim ()); at the first cycle of for. 
I did not understand what you mean by no space?

Comment: @riki: then the value is not `08:50 10:30`. `String.Split` will split by white-space characters and create an array. In this case with two strings and `HourAndMinute[1]` will access the second which is `10:30`. Maybe your `StartEnd` value is different. Use the debugger

Comment: at the first charge cycle 08:50 
after the second lap charged 10:30 ...@TimSchmelter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174432/discussion-between-riki-and-tim-schmelter).

Comment: @TimSchmelter 
I added the image of the table above